# WPF/XAML: Positioning primitives in nested data-structure within a canvas

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas

in my current Project I have a nested data-structure. The root is an ObservableCollection ( terrainModel.terrainElements). Each of the elements in the collection host another ObservableCollection(drawElements) that consists of data to draw primitives in a canvas. Depending on the primitive I provide a DataTemplate so that it is rendered in the Canvas.

Here is the actual XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding terrainModel.terrainElements}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Width="1000" Height="500" Background="Aquamarine"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding drawElements}">
                    <ItemsControl.Resources>

                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type drawtype:LineElement}">
                            <Line Stroke="Black" X1="{Binding startPoint.X}" Y1="{Binding startPoint.Y}" X2="{Binding endPoint.X}" Y2="{Binding endPoint.Y}" />
                        </DataTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type drawtype:CircleElement}">
                            <Ellipse Stroke="Black" Width="{Binding radius}" Height="{Binding radius}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type drawtype:RectangleElement}">
                            <Rectangle Stroke="Blue"  Width="{Binding width}" Height="{Binding height}" Canvas.Left="{Binding position.X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding position.Y}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>

                    </ItemsControl.Resources>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The problem is however that I am not able to set the position of the primitives correct in the XAML, as Canvas.Left="{Binding position.X}" for example does not work as it is in the inner ItemsControl and not in the outer ItemsControl.

I also tried to transform the primitives like this:

```
 <Rectangle.RenderTransform><TranslateTransform   x:Name="myTransform2" X="{Binding position.X}" Y="{Binding position.Y}" /></Rectangle.RenderTransform>
```

This worked but ruined the position of following elements to draw. Of course I could draw everything in code of the view, but I would like to know if it's also possible to do in xaml.

Answer (score 1):

The solution by Clemens worked:

> Set a Canvas as the ItemsPanel for the inner ItemsControl the same way
> you did for the outer one. Then use the RenderTransform solution, as
> setting Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top would still not work because the
> Rectangle will not become a direct child of the Canvas. You would need
> to set an ItemsContainerStyle for the Left and Top bindings.
>
> The outer Canvas should still (also) have a Canvas as its ItemsPanel.
> Otherwise you will have problems with more than one terrainElement.

I thought that a new Canvas would be generated in the inner ItemsControl for every outer ItemsControl.

Here is the XAML if somebody is interested:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding terrainModel.terrainElements}">
           <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding drawElements}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas Width="1000" Height="500" Background="Aquamarine"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                   
                    <ItemsControl.Resources>
                        
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type drawtype:LineElement}">
                            <Line Stroke="Black" X1="{Binding startPoint.X}" Y1="{Binding startPoint.Y}" X2="{Binding endPoint.X}" Y2="{Binding endPoint.Y}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                        
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type drawtype:CircleElement}">
                            <Ellipse Stroke="Black" Width="{Binding radius}" Height="{Binding radius}">
                                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform   x:Name="myTransform" X="{Binding position.X}" Y="{Binding position.Y}" />
                                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type drawtype:RectangleElement}">
                            <Rectangle Stroke="Blue"  Width="{Binding width}" Height="{Binding height}">
                                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform   x:Name="myTransform2" X="{Binding position.X}" Y="{Binding position.Y}" />
                                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </DataTemplate>

                    </ItemsControl.Resources>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```